# Error : No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement (PHP and MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert a prepared statement into database, but i keep getting an error

"Error : No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement"

heres my code snippet

```
 if(empty($name_err) && empty($address_err) && empty($testcode_err )&& empty($bi_err)){
    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cidadao (name, address, testcode,bi) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_name, $param_address, $param_testcode, $param_bi);

        // Set parameters
        $param_name = $name;
        $param_address = $address;
        $param_testcode = $testcode;
        $param_bi = $bi;

        print_r($stmt);

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){

            // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: index.php");

            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            $error = mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
            print("Error : ".$error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the parameters before you bind them?

Comment: You should be seeing a warning from `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` as you have a missing `s`. Fix that and the rest should work

Comment: @ADyson That makes no difference. NULL is an acceptable value too

Comment: @Dharman good point, thanks

Comment: thanks guys. i was missing an "s" in the stmt config . i had 4 paramenters and needed "ssss".

thanks @Dharman